# ext4 block group layout clarification

Tags: linux, filesystems, kernel, inode, ext4

I'm on an Ubuntu 22.04 x86_64 system, kernel version 6.5.0-15-generic.
I've read the ext4 documentation on kernel.org and there are some parts that are not explained very thoroughly so I hope someone could kindly clarify these for me.

The layout of a single ext4 block group is shown as follow :

[image]

What I'd like to know is :

1. What is exactly the "Reserved GDT Blocks" in few words ?
2. I know that both files and directories are represented by inodes **metadata** structures in the inode Table. So each file and directory ( which is also a kind of file ) has its inode number. Now, if the directory metadata is contained in its inode structure in the inode Table, where is the directory **data** content ? Is it inside the Data Blocks ?
3. The documentation makes a distinction between Linear ( classic ) Directories and Hash Tree Directories. Can we simply say that in both forms the directory data content just boils down essentially to a list of inode,user readable name pairs like this :

**inode number -> name of the file**

**inode number -> name of the file**

**inode number -> name of the file**

.........................................................

?

4. Do the inodes structure inside the inode Table contain information about where the file or directory is located on disk ? If so, what field inside the **struct ext4_inode** is responsible for that ?

Comment: A **question post** on Stack Overflow is intended for a **single question**.

Comment: @Tsyvarev You're right, maybe too many questions...let's do it step by step. Here is my first question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78009003/what-is-the-field-inside-the-struct-ext4-inode-responsible-for-providing-pointer