# What is the field inside the struct ext4_inode responsible for providing pointers to where data is actually located on disk?

Tags: linux, filesystems, kernel, inode, ext4

I've been reading the ext4 documentation on kernel.org and in the struct ext4_inode section it is show a field named i_block.
It says "Block map or extent tree".
Does this field contain pointers or something like that to locate the actual data on disk ?